# Auto sizing Silverlight controls

Tags: xaml, browser, layout, silverlight-4.0

I am using Silverlight 4 for a project. I want to know if there is a way I can get the main canvas to stretch to the height and width of the browser window it is hosted in?

I want the controls within to resize in proportion to the main control that hosts all the rest of the controls in the host browser window. 
This is a Prism application which has a Shell.xaml and a ContentControl within the shell.
In this prism case I want the content control to span to 100% of the screen height and width.. and when a Page.xaml loads within it I want the Page's usercontrol to fill up the entire content control of the xaml. Similarly, within the Page.xaml if I have a grid I want the grid to grow to a size no more than a fixed number of pixels

The Grid within the Page.xaml's user control seems to be sizing properly. I am having trouble getting the root user control of the Page.xaml to stretch to the entire width of the browser window. Is there a way this can be done using xaml properties only? I dont want to specify the height and width to 800 and 1200 like I have done below.

This is my code

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400" 
xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
Background="#FF2D8543" 
Height="800" Width="1200"
 >

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFEB0A0A" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
 >
</Grid>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use `Grid` instead of `Canvas` as top level element. `Grid` takes all the available space by default.

Learn more about Silverlight layout system [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/quickstarts/layout/) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645025%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

**Update:**

Just remove `Width` and `Height` attributes from the `UserControl`:

```
Height="800" Width="1200"
```

By setting those explicitly you are giving the control fixed size. If you don't specify `Width` and `Height` the control will take all the available space.

Comment: Those articles talk about sizing the control with the main UserControl. But what do I need to do to set the size of the main user control <UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ..??

Comment: this seems to work in a fresh project I created in blend. But in my prism project it doesn't.

Comment: The prism project got a shell.xaml in which I am loading the page.xaml which has the usercontrol. I have removed the height and width in both the shell and page.xaml but still no use! Any ideas?

Comment: @user20358 - Is you silverlight app hosted in a web page? If so, check that the page doesn't restrict the size. Also check that shell.xaml, page xaml and user control xaml don't contain panels like `Canvas`. And finally, make sure that you read the links I provided to understand how layout works in Silverligh.